# Converting an equation with "small displacements" retains a zeroth-order term -- can it become a PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I have come across an equation that looks like

$$ f\!\left(t + \tau, x\right) = f\!\left(t, x - \xi\right) - f\!\left(t, x + \xi\right) $$

where $\tau$ and $\xi$ are both small. Every bone in my body says "convert that to a PDE", but when I do a series expansion, I find that not all my terms are linear in the small quantities:

$$ f\!\left(t, x\right) + \tau \partial_t f\!\left(t, x\right) + \mathcal{O}\!\left(\tau^2\right) = -2 \xi \partial_x f\!\left(t, x\right) + \mathcal{O}\!\left(\xi^2\right) $$

I understand how the series expansion works and I can see how this happened, but I don't know how to proceed. If everything were linear in small quantities, I'd know how to continue.

If I take a limit as $\tau$ and $\xi$ approach zero as-is, I'll just get $f\!\left(t, x\right) = 0$. That seems like a sad and unsatisfactory ending for such a nice equation. I'm hoping someone here has another idea.

Comment: I think that it being just zero is inevitable if you assume $f$ is even just continuous. The problem is that if $f$ is continuous and not identically zero then you should expect the RHS to be way smaller than the LHS provided that the displacements are small.